# Could the Jacobian Matrix be related to curvature?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, jacobian

Imagine we have the following application:
$$
f(\mathbf r): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m
$$
We would like to find the tangent space to this application. Using the Jacobian matrix:
$$
\mathbf{J} f (\mathbf r) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}\\ \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_n}\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}
\end{pmatrix}
\\
$$
Using the basis of the $\mathrm {Im}(\mathbf{J} f)$:
$$
\mathcal B = \left \{  
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} \\ 
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} \\
\vdots \\ \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} \\ 
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} \\
\vdots \\ \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}
\end{pmatrix} \;
\dots \;
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1} \\
\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_2} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}
\end{pmatrix}
\right \} = \left \{ \mathbf e_1, \mathbf e_2 \; \dots \; \mathbf e_k \right \}
$$
It is well known, that the volume enclosed by this vectors (if $n = m$) is:
$$
d^n\mathbf r = \det{ \left ( \mathbf{J} f \right)} dx_1 dx_2 \; \dots  \;dx_n \
$$
Now, we want to see how much a vector $\mathbf e_i$ changes in every direction, given by the basis vectors of the space:
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \; \frac{\mathbf e_i (\mathbf r + t \mathbf e_j) - \mathbf e_i (\mathbf r)}{t} = \frac{\partial \mathbf e_i}{\partial x_j}
$$
This derivative measures how much, the basis vector $\mathbf e_i$, changes along the direction of the basis vector $\mathbf e_j$.

We will define a matrix where the columns are the components of the vectors $\frac{\partial \mathbf e_i}{\partial x_j}$.
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{J} f}{\partial x_j}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m
$$
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{J} f}{\partial x_j}  = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \mathbf e_1}{\partial x_j} & \frac{\partial \mathbf e_2}{\partial x_j} \; \dots \; 
\frac{\partial \mathbf e_n}{\partial x_j}
\end{pmatrix}
\\
$$
Then the change of (hyper) volume in a certain direction is given by (if $n = m$):
$$
d^n \mathbf r_j = \det \left ( \frac{\partial \mathbf{J} f}{\partial x_j} \right ) dx_1 dx_2 \; \dots  \;dx_n \
$$
My question is, could this changes in volume, be related to curvature? If a surface isn't curved, like for example, on a hyper-plane, this volume wouldn't change. Is this reasonable? Did I made wrong assumptions?

Comment: I don't understand. If $n=m$ you are reparametrizing an $n$-dimensional region in $\Bbb R^n$. Curvature of what? In the case $n<m$, you might be interested in looking at the method of moving frames for analyzing submanifolds and their curvatures. For the case $n=2$ and $m=3$, this is the case of surfaces and if you're familiar with differential forms, you might look at Section 3 of Chapter 3 of my differential geometry text (linked in my profile). I can recommend thorough texts on moving frames if you are interested.